# Semantic HTML for 1 line of text

Tags: html, semantics, markup

I have a div containing an event I want it to look like this

```
[-----]   TITLE
[-IMG-]   Author
[-----]   Date
```

The way I have it set up now is like this

```
<div class="book">
    <img class="thumb">
    <h2>TITLE</h3>
    <span>Author</span>
    <br />
    <span>Date</span>
</div>
```

I don't think that I should be using `<span>` for the author and Description since I want them on multiple lines (also doing `display:block` makes it act weird with the floated element to the left) but I don't know if a `<p>` tag is suitable since it's only 1 line of text.

What tag should I be using for this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please include your CSS or a screenshot or http://jsfiddle.net/ of your current code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author is a subheader, i would use `<h3>` as for date the ideal would be to use [HTML 5 time tag](http://html5doctor.com/element-index/#time) but this brings some complications in older browsers and IE so i would recommend using `<p>` if you want the line break.

```
<div class="book">
    <img class="thumb" alt="">
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <h3>Author</h3>
    <p>Date</p>
</div>
```

This elements will give you the line brakes you want and are semantically correct.

P.D: As @Will Martin mentioned it is recommended that you use the `alt` attribute with the image tag.

Comment: sorry I had a typo, it was date not description, so I have 2 "1 liners".. i don't think i shouldhave another subheader since then i have no content. I suppose I could do a list?

Comment: +1, also make sure to add an ALT attribute to that IMG tag for screen reader users.

Comment: amosriveras example creates a wrong outline. The Author is not a sub-heading! In this example the date belongs to the author, not the title. Also the date is not a paragraph of text, so `p` is wrong here, too.

Comment: @unor coming back to this answer, i agree with you. what do you think are is the correct set up?

Comment: @amosrivera: I added an answer, starting with your example

Answer (score 1):

While not strictly paragraphs, I think that the `<p>` tag is most appropriate here.

You are separating out different, but related, types of information.  Just because it isn't in sentence form, doesn't mean it doesn't make some sense to use `<p>`, with classes for the type of information in them.

Whichever you end up deciding, remember that the design is separate from the elements.  That is, the fact that they are on different lines shouldn't be your primary decision point.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with [amosriveras answer from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6657154/1591669), I'd do things different:

### HTML 4.01:

```
<div class="book">
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <img class="thumb" alt="">
    <div>Author</div>
    <div>Date</div>
</div>
```

- the `h2` has to be the first element, otherwise the `img` would not be part of this heading scope
- "Author" is no heading content; also this would mean that the "Date" belongs to the Author heading scope (it should belong to the "TITLE" instead). So use a `div` instead of a `h3` (no, not `p`, because it is not a paragraph)
- "Date" is not a paragraph, so use a `div` instead of `p`

### HTML5:

```
<article class="book">
    <img class="thumb" alt="">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <div>Author</div>
    <div><time>Date</time></div>
</article>
```

- using `article` instead of `div`
- now the "TITLE" heading can be placed anywhere in this article; also it can become a `h1`
- using [`time`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-time-element.html#the-time-element) for "Date"

Using a `dl` would be possible, too:

```
<article class="book">
    <img class="thumb" alt="">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <dl>
     <dt>Author</dt>
     <dd>AUTHOR NAME</dd>
     <dt>Date</dt>
     <dd><time>DATE</time></dd>
    </dl>
</article>
```

- the `img` *could* be placed in a `dd`, for example with a `dt` "Photo" or something like that (depends on the context). I'd only do that if the image is really relevant to the book/event.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @Mazlix's comment on @Amosrivera's answer, I'd like to suggest a definition list.

```
<dl>
    <dt><img class="thumb" alt="book cover" /> TITLE</dt>
    <dd class="author">AUTHOR</dd>
    <dd class="date>DATE</dd>
</dl>
```

The styling might get tetchy if you try to a single DL with multiple DT/DD pairs within it, but you could just as easily use a whole bunch of definition lists.

EDIT:

@David Thomas beat me to the punch there.  Ah well, c'est la vie.